# Replace Blank/empty cell with a string value

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

Hope someone can help.  I need to populate any blank/empty cells within a range of cells with a specific string.  I also don't know that the last row would be in that range so I am looking for that first, I know that line of code works as I have used it for another function within the script.  Below is the code I am using: -

```
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each r In Range("AS22:AU" & LastRow)
        If r.Value2 = vbNullString Then
            r.Value2 = "Greens"
        End If
    Next
```

I don't seem to get any compile errors when I run the code, it just does not work, I still have the same blank/empty cells.

Can anyone shed any light onto what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use the [`.Replace` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194086.aspx) with the range. It would be much quicker.

```
Range("AS22:AU" & LastRow).Replace "", "Greens", xlWhole
```

Comment: @Iturner I did try that, but got the same results - Nothing.  the cells stayed blanks.  this is what I had originally                                    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row                                With Range("AS22:AU" & LastRow)
            .Replace what:="", Replacement:="On Track"
End With

Comment: Are there formulas within the cells which are causing the cells to show as blank? Have you debugged to ensure that the `LastRow` variable is returning the expected integer?

Comment: @Iturner I will just run LastRow and check that it is returning a value

Comment: @Iturner Thanks I checked this and wasn't getting the correct cell number, I changed the column I was running LastRow on and I now get the results I wanted. - Thanks

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r As Range, LastRow As Long

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each r In Range("AS22:AU" & LastRow)
        If r.Text = "" Then r.Value = "Greens"
    Next r
End Sub
```

This will change:

- truly empty cells
- cells containing formulas returning *Null*
- cells containing *Null* character as a constant

Comment: this does not work either, the cells stay blank - Any clues as to what this is

Comment: @user3088476  I suspect the **2** in the equation for `LastRow` ............are you sure you want column **B** to control the end of the loop ??

Comment: The column B is a column I know I will contain a value in the last row, the column AS - AU which I am copying in may not contain a value within the last row, this is why I am searching on column B.

Comment: @user3088476  Perhaps the cells in `AS:AU` only **appear** empty.................. perhaps they contain a **single space** ??

Comment: @ Gary's I have it working now - thanks for you help and input

Answer (score 0):

Use `IsEmpty()` to test for blanks.

```
    If IsEmpty(r.Value2) Or Trim(r.Value2) = "" Then
        r.Value2 = "Greens"
    End If
```

Also watch out for cells with a zero length string or a space. They appear empty but in fact are not.