# VBA procedure: Replace blanks within a table-works, but why?

Tags: excel, vba

I've referenced this site to answer many of my questions, but this is one I couldn't find an answer to.

```
Public Sub RemoveBlanks()
Dim Table As ListObject
Set Table = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("ExampleTable")
Dim r As Range

With Table.DataBodyRange
    For Each r In Table.DataBodyRange
        If r.Value = "" Then r.Value = "-"
    Next r

End With

End Sub
```

This is the code I used(changed variable/sheet names to generic for ease of conversation).

Declared the variable
`Dim r As Range`
But never set a reference or defined what r is.
So how does this part work? I thought that for each variable a value or reference had to be assigned for VBA to know what to do with it.

```
For Each r In Table.DataBodyRange
        If r.Value = "" Then r.Value = "-"
    Next r
```

I'm looking for the why.

This is my first post, and I am very green at this programmiing/coding business-Google has been my friend. I'm looking for more theory instead of the good old copy/paste the code in, make a few name changes, and cross my fingers.

My appologies if the formating isn't perfect. 
I'm happy to clarify if what I'm asking doesn't make sense.

Comment: `For Each r` is what performs the assignment - each cell in `DatabodyRange` is sequentially assigned to `r`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/for-eachnext-statement  FYI your `With` block isn't doing anything here.

Comment: The `For Each r In...` bit sets the `r` variable to the cells in the table, one cell at a time.

Comment: You may be thinking of something like ```for i = 1 to 10``` that works a little differently than a ```for each```

Comment: Thanks guys for the quick reply.  Yes my goal was for it to look in each cell in the table. Thankfully i found the code on here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35746759/replace-blank-empty-cell-with-a-string-value     I just didn't understand how r was defined as each cell. @TimWilliams ty for the reference!

Comment: I would probably write it as `For Each r In Table.DataBodyRange.Cells` to be more explicit about what the code is doing

Comment: @TimWilliams changes made. Thanks for the help!